# Error del atributo no existe dentro de la clase

Tags: python

tengo creado dentro del codigo esta parte para obtener el calendario.

```
self.calendario_inicio_factura = DateEntry(caja1)#calentario
self.calendario_inicio_factura.grid(row=3,column=1, padx=0)
    
self.calendario_final_factura = DateEntry(caja1)#calendario
self.calendario_final_factura.grid(row=3,column=2, padx=0)
```

y dentro de la consulta estoy haciando la llamada al calendario, para intentar visualizar por fechas los datos del Treeview, pero recibo: que la clase donde se encuentra no tiene definido:

> AttributeError: 'PRODUCTOS' object has no attribute
> 'calendario_inicio_factura'

lo que ya defini dentro de la consulta: 'calendario_inicio_factura', que podria estar pasando?

```
def consulta_facturas(self):
        book = self.cuadro_blanco_facturas.get_children()
        for elementos in book:
            self.cuadro_blanco_facturas.delete(elementos)
        query = f"SELECT nro, id_cliente, nombre, forma_pago, total, fecha FROM reporte_cuadre WHERE fecha >= '{self.calendario_inicio_factura}' and fecha <= '{self.calendario_final_factura}'"#
        rows = self.run_query(query)#query
        for row in rows:
            id = row[0]#de menor a mayor
            self.cuadro_blanco_facturas.insert("",END, id, text=id, values=row)
```

de acuerdo al comentario intento agregarlo a la clase, ejecuta, pero no muestra resultado ni error.

```
def __init__(self,root, valor1 = DateEntry.get_date, valor2 = DateEntry.get_date):
        self.calendario_inicio_factura = valor1
        self.calendario_final_factura = valor2
```

> Adjunto todo el codigo

```
from tkinter import E, N, Frame, IntVar, LabelFrame, LEFT, RIGHT, BOTTOM, StringVar, Label, Button, END, Toplevel, Entry, Tk, font
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, Spinbox
import sqlite3
import tkinter

#mostrar imagines
import datetime
from tkcalendar import DateEntry
from datetime import timedelta

import time

class PRODUCTOS():
    base_datos = "clientes_productos.db"

   
    def __init__(self,root, valor1 = DateEntry.get_date, valor2 = DateEntry.get_date):
        self.wind = root #ventana completa
        self.wind.title('Facturacion principal')
        self.wind.geometry("850x600")
        self.calendario_inicio_factura = valor1
        self.calendario_final_factura = valor2
              

        #Las divisiones de la ventana, caja 1 arriba, caja 2 abajo
        caja1 = LabelFrame(self.wind, text="", font=("Calibri",14), padx=2, pady=2)#aleja lo q se encuentra dentro
        caja2 = LabelFrame(self.wind, text="Facturas", font=("Calibri",12), padx=1, pady=1)
        caja3 = LabelFrame(self.wind, text="", font=("Calibri",12), padx=2, pady=2)
        caja1.pack(fill="both", expand=True, padx=20, pady=10, ipady=10, ipadx=5)#pady = aleja a la caja 2, X aleja de la esquina derecha
        caja2.pack(fill="both", expand=True, padx=20, pady=10, ipady=100, ipadx=5)#ipady alarga el labelframe
        caja3.pack(fill="both", expand=True, padx=20, pady=10, ipady=30, ipadx=5)


        #los encabezados del cuadro blanco arriba
        self.cuadro_blanco_facturas = ttk.Treeview(caja2, columns=("1","2","3","4","5","6"), show="headings", height=10)#Height largo del Scrollbar
        self.cuadro_blanco_facturas.pack(side=LEFT)#scrollbar
        self.cuadro_blanco_facturas.place(x=0, y=0)#scrollbar
        self.cuadro_blanco_facturas.heading("1", text="Nro_Fact.")
        self.cuadro_blanco_facturas.heading("2", text="ID-Cliente")
        self.cuadro_blanco_facturas.heading("3", text="Nombre del Cliente")
        self.cuadro_blanco_facturas.heading("4", text="Forma de Pago")
        self.cuadro_blanco_facturas.heading("5", text="Total")
        self.cuadro_blanco_facturas.heading("6", text="Fecha")

        #tamano de las columnas vertical
        self.cuadro_blanco_facturas.column("1", width=70)# width= anchura, minwidth = lo minimo de esa anchura
        self.cuadro_blanco_facturas.column("2", width=70)
        self.cuadro_blanco_facturas.column("3", width=250)
        self.cuadro_blanco_facturas.column("4", width=120)#minwidth=120
        self.cuadro_blanco_facturas.column("5", width=100)
        self.cuadro_blanco_facturas.column("6", width=120)
        #horizontal
        self.cuadro_blanco_facturas.column('#0', width=50, minwidth=100)#Yscrollbar1
        

        self.consulta_facturas() #llamada a la TABLA

        #scrollbar VERTICAL lado derecho cuadro blanco 
        yscrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(caja2, orient="vertical", command=self.cuadro_blanco_facturas.yview)
        yscrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill="y")

        #scrollbar HORIZONTAL lado derecho cuadro blanco
        xscrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(caja2, orient="horizontal", command=self.cuadro_blanco_facturas.xview)
        xscrollbar.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill="x")

        self.cuadro_blanco_facturas.configure(yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set, xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set)
        
        #CUADRO CAJA 1
        variable = StringVar()
        #Label(self.wind, textvariable=variable).pack(padx=10, pady=10)
        
        
        #Button ventana de busqueda 2
        btn5 = Button(caja1, text = "...", command=self.consulta_facturas)
        btn5.grid(row = 0, column = 2, pady=5, padx=0, ipady=1, ipadx=1)

        
        self.calendario_inicio_factura = DateEntry(caja1)#calentario
        self.calendario_inicio_factura.grid(row=3,column=1, padx=0)
    
        self.calendario_final_factura = DateEntry(caja1)#calendario
        self.calendario_final_factura.grid(row=3,column=2, padx=0)

        #botones de abajo primera pantalla
        #CONEXION DEL SQL-LITE
   
    #consulta para agregar clientes
    def run_query(self,query, tupla=()): #query= es el query de busqueda SQL
        with sqlite3.connect(self.base_datos) as conn: #tupla= recibe los datos dentro de su tupla
            self.cursor = conn.cursor()
            result = self.cursor.execute(query, tupla)
            conn.commit()
            return result

    def consulta_facturas(self):
        
        fecha_inicio2 = self.calendario_inicio_factura
        fecha_final2 = self.calendario_final_factura
        book = self.cuadro_blanco_facturas.get_children()
        for elementos in book:
            self.cuadro_blanco_facturas.delete(elementos)
        query = f"SELECT nro, id_cliente, nombre, forma_pago, total, fecha FROM reporte_cuadre WHERE fecha >= '{fecha_inicio2}' and fecha <= '{fecha_final2}'"#
        rows = self.run_query(query)#query
        for row in rows:
            id = row[0]#de menor a mayor
            #self.cuadro_blanco_cliente.insert('',0, text=row[1], values=row)
            self.cuadro_blanco_facturas.insert("",END, id, text=id, values=row)

    
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    product = PRODUCTOS(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Agrega la clase

Comment: te refieres a esto? def __init__(self,root, valor1 = DateEntry.get_date, valor2 = DateEntry.get_date): self.calendario_inicio_factura = valor1 self.calendario_final_factura = valor2

Comment: La verdad, no se si la parte donde se crean los calendarios y la parte de la función pertenecen o no a la misma clase. No puedo decir mucho con fragmentos de código aqui y alla. Te recomiendo colocar un [emcv](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para que sea mas facil ayudarte.

Comment: listo adjunte el resto del codigo, ejecuta, pero no visualiza nada de la base de datos, ni presenta ningun error el python,

Comment: En el `__init__()` tienes está asignación: `self.calendario_inicio_factura = valor1`, que vendría siendo `self.calendario_inicio_factura = DateEntry.get_date`. ¿Por que asignas una función al calendario?

Comment: @CandidMoe xq es la funcion que devuelve las fechas 2022/11/29 que deceo hacer coincidir con la columna fecha del query al momento de utilizar el widget

Comment: Tienes una función en `self.calendario_inicio_factura`, pero nunca la llamas como función `self.calendario_inicio_factura()`. Eso me confunde

Comment: @CandidMoe ese es el DataEntry, que llama al calendario cuando ejecutar el APP. pero al momento de ponerlo al query dice: AttributeError: 'PRODUCTOS' object has no attribute 'calendario_inicio_factura' x eso intente lo del comentario de agregarlo a la clase.

Answer (score 1):

La solucion era declarar estas variables dentro del inicializador de clase

```
self.calendario_inicio_factura = DateEntry()
self.calendario_final_factura = DateEntry()
```

ya luego me deja llamar a los GET_DATE sin presentar error.

```
fecha_inicio2 = self.calendario_inicio_factura.get_date()
fecha_final2 = self.calendario_final_factura.get_date()
```